# Keeping content "fixed" under slideshow of different image sizes

Tags: css, html, position, slideshow

This is a very basic CSS question, but I am struggling with it:

I have a slideshow plugin featuring images of different sizes. The content underneath shifts up and down relative to the image sizes. How can I fix the text below such that it remains steady underneath these different images?

Link is here: http://bit.ly/1ianglg

Thank you!

Comment: I think the OP's issue wass fixed.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because of auto height on you slide container
Add `min-height` or fixed `height` to your `div.rslides_container` containing sliding images giving min-height will defend your content moving while slide height changes according to your img height.

for example

```
     .rslides_container {
margin-bottom: 50px;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
min-height: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped.

Comment: I have a question related to this site; it may merit a new thread, but maybe not: can you guide me on how to align the images as close as possible to the "center" of the page, vertically and horizontally, while still keeping the menu stable at the bottom?

Comment: Already the slider is centered horizontally..Am not get sure why vertical?

Comment: Also if the Answer is Correct means Don't forgot to mark it as Answer

Comment: Thanks! Answer is marked. And as for the "centering"--is it possible to orient the entire slider to the "middle" of the page? One way I can think of doing this is altering each image such that there is a frame of white space around each, essentially rendering them all the same size (but visually "centered")...but is there a way to do this in CSS? Basically, is there a way, regardless of image size, to align the center of each image as close as possible to the center of the page?